# How to loop the edge animation to marching ant in cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, diagram, cytoscape.js

How do I make the edge animate like in marching ant and point it towards the target node?

I tried using the `line-dash-offset` property like this but it doesn't loop.

style

```
{
      selector: "edge",
      style: {
        "curve-style": "taxi",
        width: 2,
        "target-arrow-shape": "triangle",
        "target-arrow-color": "#9dbaea",
        "line-style": "dashed",
        "line-dash-pattern": [8, 4],
      }
    }
```

animation

```
let loopAnimation = eles => {
  eles.animation(
      {
        style: {
          "line-dash-offset": 24,
          "line-dash-pattern": [8, 4],
        }
      },
      {
        duration: 1000
      }
  ).play().promise('complete').then(() => loopAnimation(eles))
};

cy.edges().forEach(loopAnimation);
```

[image: diagram]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by calling reverse() before you play it

```
let loopAnimation = eles => {
  const ani = eles.animation(
      {
        style: {
          "line-dash-offset": 24,
          "line-dash-pattern": [8, 4],
        }
      },
      {
        duration: 1000
      }
  );

  ani.reverse().play().promise('complete').then(() => loopAnimation(eles))
};
```